# Calculus Spivak Ch. 11 Theorem 7

Tags: real-analysis

To begin, I know there is another thread for this same question but I truly didn't understand it. ([Spivak Ch 11 Theorem 7](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/769463/spivak-ch-11-theorem-7))

My question is simply how does $\lim \limits_{x \to a} f'(x) = \lim \limits_{h \to 0} f'({\alpha}_{h})$, when only the former is assumed? Because if the latter is assumed, it's relatively straightforward, since $|\alpha - a| < |h|$ and you just let $x = \alpha$.

[image: l]

Comment: You realize Spivak has written more than one text, right?  The reference is not terribly helpful.

Comment: Must be $\mathbf{Calculus}$.